# Comparar dos objectos en Java antes de hacer un update

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

Estoy teniendo problemas con algo que a priori me parecía sencillo.

```
public ResponseData update(Order order) throws BusinessException, DaoException {
    Order orderOld = orderDao.get(order.getIdOrder());
    order.setIsPaid(orderOld.getIsPaid());
    order.setIsInvitation(orderOld.getIsInvitation());
    order = orderDao.update(order);
    return this.process(order);
}
```

En el método update, recibo un pedido (Order), pero antes de hacer update quiero asegurarme de que los valores de "isPaid" y "isInvitation" no cambien. Pero si pongo un punto de interrupción, veo que order y orderOld tienen siempre exactamente los mismos valores.

¿Cómo podría hacer esto?

Gracias!

Comment: Es más seguro hacerlo al revés. Modifica lo campos que sí quieras actualizar y actualiza el objeto que viene de la base. Respecto a tu duda, estás haciendo un set del get del objeto old, para comparar el valor pon el punto antes de esa línea.

Comment: Hola! Gracias por tu tiempo! He probado a poner el punto de interrupción en diferentes sitios, pero es lo mismo. Pero si modifico primero los datos que sí quiero actualizar, me podría encontrar con que la tabla tiene 1000 campos, o con que aunque no tenga tantos, mañana mi jefe me pida que le añada algún campo, y tendría que venir al update a añadir también ese campo. ¿Por qué no se puede hacer de esa manera que estoy intentando?

Comment: No entiendo tu pregunta: *quiero asegurarme de que los valores de "isPaid" y "isInvitation" no cambien* ¿qué no cambien con respecto a qué? ¿dónde haces esa comprobación?

Comment: En la bd hay un "order" (oldOrder) y con la llamada el método update se pretende actualizar ese "order" (pasando un "newOrder"). Lo que pretendo es que todos los atributos se actualicen, excepto esos dos (isPaid y isActive), que tienen que conservar los valores que tenían antes del update (los que tenía oldOrder).

Comment: Pues escribe una sentencia UPDATE que actualice únicamente las columnas que quieres... `UPDATE laTabla SET laColumnaQueQuiero = unValor, laOtraColumnaQueQuiero= otroValor WHERE unaColumna=unCriterio` esa sentencia actualizará únicamente dos columnas, dejando a todas las demás intactas.

Comment: Como decía en el otro comentario, lo puedo hacer así, pero no me parecía la forma más eficiente, si es que hay otra, puesto que mañana me pueden añadir más columnas a la tabla o bien podría ser una tabla con 100 columnas, y sería bastante tedioso tener que updatearlas una por una.

Comment: Respecto a tu respuesta, mañana agregas un campo que no se tiene que actualizar y debes venir y quitarlo, no es peor ni mejor. Solo me parece más seguro para que no te actualicen algo que no quieras que te actualicen. Igual tu problema no es actualizar, es que dices que el campo que lees de la base tiene el mismo valor que el campo quw te envían. Al menos eso aclaraste con el brake point. Debes entender qué estás leyendo y recibiendo o aclararlo mejor para poder ayudarte. Slds!